# gitlab: Runner is offline, last contact was about some hours ago

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

recently my runners have been stopped and I don't know why?

I've just upgraded `nodejs` on the server and it did happen.

after this problem, I've tried to update `gitlab` to the latest version and check the runner status but the problem still persists and in the title of grey icon shows:

> Runner is offline, the last contact was about 22 hours ago.

[image: Runner is offline, the last contact was about 22 hours ago]

**What should I do?**

and when I try to `Retry stuck jobs`, see this error:

> This job is stuck, because you don't have any active runners online with any of these tags assigned to them: 'my label'.

*Any Help is appreciated!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't why but I found the `gitlab-runner` was completely out of service. I've tried to fix it. at the first step, I've updated the `gitlab-runner` bit it didn't work. after that I decided to reinstall the gitlab-runner so I've met this steps:

1. removing the gitlab-runner user with this command line: `sudo deluser --remove-home gitlab-runner`
2. following the manual installation and configuration on [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html).

and it worked.

Comment: Yes. For me worked too. But only if install from package and not by "sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner" command.

Answer (score 33):

To me, the following solved the problem:

```
gitlab-runner restart
```

Where `gitlab-runner` is a symlink to [`gitlab-ci-multi-runner`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html):

> GitLab Runner is the open source project that is used to run your jobs and send the results back to GitLab. It is used in conjunction with GitLab CI, the open-source continuous integration service included with GitLab that coordinates the jobs.

Comment: I tried to restart several times but it did not work

Comment: This didn't worked for me. Instead, `sudo gitlab-runner verify` restarted all the runners

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me:

```
sudo gitlab-runner verify
```

since `gitlab-runner restart` didn't actually restarted runners

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had registered multiple runners and removed them from the Gitlab UI. This cleaned up the stale runners.

Comment: This helped me realize I'd goofed in my config.toml file.

Comment: How do you do that through the UI though? I don't think there's a command line in there anywhere that I can access.

Comment: This helped me see that it was a certificate issue

Answer (score 7):

If you runner is run under systemd

```
journalctl -u gitlab-runner.service
```

may prove enlightening. It did in my case.

```
gitlab-runner[18449]: FATAL: chdir /home/gitlab-runner: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Sharing my experience for future readers.

In my case, the internet was not working on the machine in which gitlab-runner was installed.

I have fixed the internet issue on my gitlab-runner's machine and everything works as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have internet access on that machine as well, but I can't fix that. Why does it need internet connection anyway?

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was, that the URL of our self-hosted GitLab changed. I had to change the URL of the runners manually:

```
sudo vi /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
```

After restarting, I could verify that all runners were back online:

```
sudo gitlab-runner restart
sudo gitlab-runner verify
```

Answer (score 1):

after restart gitlab-runner , you can use this for new register runner :

```
gitlab-runner restart

gitlab-runner register --name my-runner --url http://gitlab.example.com --registration-token my-registration-token
```

Answer (score 1):

Check gitlab-runner logs with `journalctl -u gitlab-runner -f`

For me the problem was:

```
gitlab-runner[2023]: FATAL: Service run failed                           error=chdir /var/lib/gitlab-runner: no such file or directory
```

so created the folder and restarted gitlab-runner

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/gitlab-runner
sudo gitlab-runner restart
```

probably something to do with installation not run by root user

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after [upgrading](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#upgrading-to-gitlab-runner-10) from an old gitlab-runner (9.5.1 -> 11.11.4) I couldn't get my runner to work. Even after removing it and registering a new one.
I noticed that my `config.toml` file didn't have the token that matches the one in the Runner CI/CD Settings page for my new runner.

I did the following to get it to work:

1. Remove the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file (perhaps
   unnecessary)
2. Click on `Reset runners registration token` in Gitlab under project's CI/CD Settings -> Runner page while registering a new runner (`gitlab-runner register`)
3. Continue with runner registration as usual.

After that, my runner was picked up and worked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but using gitlab runner on GKE. To fix it I just deleted the gitlab-runner pod. A new pod was initialized and the connection was up again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting this old thread.

I'm currently working on making a gitlab runner that works locally.
Still in the early phases, but eventually it will become very relevant.
It doesn't seem like gitlab want/have time to make this, so here you go.
https://github.com/firecow/gitlab-runner-local

Answer (score 0):

For gitlab `15.7.1` and `15.8.0`, this is what I did to resolve disconnecting runners symptoms:

- make sure home directory exists, create if it doesn't:

  ```
  sudo mkhomedir_helper gitlab-runner
  ```
- make sure `--working-directory` is set to gitlab-runner home in
  `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service`
- running stop told me to run daemon-reload and then restarted the service:

  ```
  sudo service gitlab-runner stop
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  sudo service gitlab-runner stop
  sudo service gitlab-runner start
  sudo service gitlab-runner status
  ```